# How to use an lcd panel as keyboard?

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen, keyboard, lcd

I'm quite new to raspberry pi and custom Projects but I'd like to use an lcd touch panel like this (https://bit.ly/39HZpe4) as a keyboard for my raspberry pi 3 model b.

I saw this in this video: https://youtu.be/gpBfqZTWCHs

How do I have to setup the raspi to have it detect the lcd as a keyboard?

I'd have to write a proper driver, I suppose.

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: LCDs are not touch sensitive .... if you require touch input, then you need to get a touch panel that fits over top of the LCD

Answer (score 1):

That panel is a resistive touch screen which needs analog inputs. Since the Rpi does not have analog inputs you cannot use it directly.

If you really want to use it a a keyboard I would use an a microcontroller to interface with the touch screen and then have the microcontroller emulate a USB keyboard.

The microcontroller  would read the touch sensor, translate the x,y coordinates to a particular key press and then send that key press over usb as if it was a keyboard.

Circuitpython has libraries for interfacing with touch sensors and to act as a USB keyboard. That is where I would start.

- [CircuitPython](https://circuitpython.org/)
- [CircuitPython Touchscreen library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Touchscreen)
- [CircuitPython HID device tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-essentials/circuitpython-hid-keyboard-and-mouse)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the Input.

I searched around the web the whole day and all I really found was these two boards:

https://www.adafruit.com/product/1580

https://www.adafruit.com/product/1571

The first one seems to be the better choice since the 2nd board only has libraries for Arduino.

The first board is able to be recognized as HID device but I'm still unsure about how to put it all together. I'd really appreciate some more help ^^"

Comment: The CircuitPython seems to be limited to the corresponding Hardware from adafruit, which does not seem to contain a resistive touch Controller. But maybe I'm thinking in the wrong direction ^^"

Comment: The 2 products you linked to act as a mouse or digitizer tablet not a keyboard. I believe you can interface directly from many of the Circuit python boards to a 4 wire resistive touch panel using analog inputs. I have not done it myself so I can't give you specifics.